# What does this light blue tile mean?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

Occasionally while doing the Tempest Trials (I don't think its specific to that, but it's where I've been noticing it happening), I see a light blue tile when trying to move a unit. It happens with Sonya most, if not all, of the times I've seen it. For reference, this is what I'm referring to (the square directly above Sonya):

[image: light blue tile]

What does this tile mean? I don't think it represents a tile I can attack from, because it doesn't show up in most other cases where this would be applicable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A light blue tile is a tile that your hero will be utilizing one of their abilities/passives to move to.

One example I can immediately recall is [Wings of Mercy](https://feheroes.gamepedia.com/Wings_of_Mercy), though I'm not sure what ability/passive is triggering in your screenshot.

Comment: Now that you say that, I realized Sonya was only able to move one space up, which means Rebecca must've had Obstruct. I guess the light blue tiles are for other people's passives, as well.

Comment: You're both correct, this happens when an ability affects a units movement in any way. This can be from the unit's own skills, such as Wings of Mercy or Escape Route, from an ally's skills such as Guidance, or from an enemies skills such as Obstruct :)